# How to pass params into a mailer method? Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm using `Rails 6` and `ActionMailer`. I'm working on sending a mail to the user everytime his post is commented on. Here's my code:

app/mailers/comment_mailer.rb

```
class CommentMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def comment_mail
    @user = params[:user]

    mail(to: @user.email, subject: "Comments")
  end
end
```

app/controllers/comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    comment.user_id = current_user.id
    if comment.save
      CommentMailer.with(user: @user).comment_mail.deliver_now
      redirect_to post_path(comment.post.id)
    end
  end
```

app/views/comment_mailer/comment_mail.haml

```
%h4
  Hi
  - @user.name
%p Someone commented your post! Click the link below to see it:
  (I haven't done the link step yet)
```

After following this tutorial: https://dev.to/morinoko/sending-emails-in-rails-with-action-mailer-and-gmail-35g4 I had this Error:

```
NoMethodError in CommentsController#create
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

My console:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass):


app/mailers/comment_mailer.rb:5:in `comment_mail'
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:8:in `create'
Started POST "/comments" for 172.17.0.1 at 2020-07-01 00:32:38 +0000
Cannot render console from 172.17.0.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1
Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"Mf15U/OG9DX3SKwoBRHE/D/xENBocTtdcS07aUur+p/tGJAWSxYSP65kovzhLXHXBjvs/Wzp2dV4/1+L4nxrdQ==", "comment"=>{"content"=>"well said!", "post_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Comment"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:7:in `create'
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:7:in `create'
  Post Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:7:in `create'
  Comment Create (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "comments" ("content", "user_id", "post_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["content", "well said!"], ["user_id", 1], ["post_id", 2], ["created_at", "2020-07-01 00:32:38.439626"], ["updated_at", "2020-07-01 00:32:38.439626"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:7:in `create'
   (1.1ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:7:in `create'
CommentMailer#comment_email: processed outbound mail in 1.4ms
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 54ms (ActiveRecord: 3.6ms | Allocations: 29044)
```

I used `binding.pry` to review the `comment_mail` method and I had `@user` `>> nil` as return.

Comment: where are you setting the `@user` variable in that controller?  I assume it is not `current_user` but is instead the user who posted the post being commented on, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `CommentMailer.with(user: @user).comment_mail.deliver_now`
You haven't actually defined `@user` you mentioned that you have a user attached to the post record so use that

comment.post.user
so now you have

```
CommentMailer.with(user: comment.post.user).comment_mail.deliver_now
```

Or you make user a parameter of comment_mail

```
class CommentMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def comment_mail(user)
    @user = user #and this makes @user available in your templates

    mail(to: @user.email, subject: "Comments")
  end
end
```

And as you would expect call it like so

```
CommentMailer.comment_mail(comment.post.user).deliver_now #or preferably deliver_later
```

Comment: But it is an email notification of a comment (on what I would assume is some kind of post), the `current_user` is not likely the one who created the post being commented on, and even if they were, they probably do not want notifications when they comment on their own post, although without more info I could be wrong.

Comment: Thank you @jamesc ! I used associations to define `user = comment.post.user`  in the comment controller and works.

Comment: @RockwellRice That's a very good point. I might have to use unless `user == current_user` statement so I wont send notifications to the current user.

Comment: @viatech I have amended my answer, accordingly, glad you got it working

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that comment `belong_to` posts, or whatever is being commented on, and then also assuming posts `belong_to` a user.  You need to populate that `@user` variable. Something like:

```
@user = comment.post.user
```

To get the user of the post being commented on.

I think this should then work

```
CommentMailer.comment_mail(@user).deliver_now
```

and then update the method itself

```
def comment_mail(user)
  @user = user

  mail(to: @user.email, subject: "Comments")
end
```

You should also be able to then use the `@user` object in the mail view template too if you want to.